# Let $A\in M_n$ and $A\ge0$ and $A$ has a positive eigenvector $x$. Can we say that $Ax=\rho(A)x $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and $A\ge0$ and $A$ has a positive eigenvector $x_0$.

Can we say that(  by Perron-Frobenius theorem) $Ax_0=\rho(A)x_0 $?

(Note :$\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$   $\}$))

Comment: I think you meant: There exists a positive $x$ with $Ax=\rho x$. The existence of a positive eigenvector follows from the invariance of the positive quadrant. But there might be more than one positive eigenvector, and if you pick the wrong one your statement will fail.

Answer (score 2):

I hope we are talking about real vector spaces not one over an arbitrary ordered field. I will cheat and use some analysis.

$A$ maps the positive quadrant into itself: if $x> 0$ then $Ax> 0$,
if $A$ is strictly positive then: if $0\not=x\ge 0$ then $Ax>0$. 
On a compact set of non-negative directions the map $A$ is continuous, and therefore has a fix point (not entirely trivial) inside the strictly positive quadrant. That proves that there exists a positive eigenvector $v$ with positive eigenvalue $\mu$. 
Now pick a non -non-negative eigenvector $w$ (that is at least one coordinate is negative) with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
 Let $a$ be such a small number that $z=v+ a w$ is in the positive quadrant.
Then $A^n(z)=\mu^n v+a\lambda^n w$. By invariance $A^n(z)$ stays in the positive quadrant. But if $|\lambda|>|\mu|$ then the direction of $A^n(z)$ will align with the direction of $w$, which is not in the positive quadrant.
Thus $|\lambda|\le |\mu|$. Equality is possible $(a,b)\mapsto (b,a)$ has eigenvalues 1 and -1.

For $A\ge 0$ use some sort of continuity argument (hand waiving).

Remark that we proved that each "positive direction" eigenvalue is not smaller than any "not positive direction" eigenvalue.